# Excel Rolling Mean of 3 Similar Consecutive Observations

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the rolling mean of time series while ignoring values that do not follow the trend.

```
x
869
1570
946 
0
1136
```

So, what I would want the result to look like is...

```
x    |   y
869  |   0
1570 |   0
946  |   1128.33
3    |   0
1136 |   1217.33 ([1136+1570+946]/3)   
900  |   2982 ([946+1136+900]/3)
860  |   2896
```

The tough part here is if the row I'm on is a trending value I want to take the 3 previous trending values and find them mean of them, but if it's a non-trending value I want it to just zero out. Sometimes I might have to skip 2 or 3 previous lines to get 3 trending values to take the average as well.

So far I've been using array, RC formulas in a VBA macro form, but I'm not sure I could use RC here or if it has to be something else completely.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you identify "values that do not follow the trend"?

Comment: I guess that's another issue.  I haven't definitely figured a way out to ID them.  Let's say for experiment sake +-2 standard deviations from the mean of the entire vector.  It's time series data that starts off high and then curves down approaching 0 as x approaches infinity (theoretically).  Not sure if you're familiar with it, but it's oil production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I can help you with your problem. First three notes:

1) It appears to me that you are trying to do DCA on smoothed production profiles, ignoring months without a complete record or no data. I'm making this assumption since you mentioned this was time series data but didn't give a sample rate. 2) I've added some extra 'data' for the sake of demo-ing. 3) In your example you shared, the last two values in your 'Y' column it looks like you may have summed but have forgotten to divide.

The solution I came up with has three parts: 1) create a metric to identify 'outliers'; 2) flag 'outliers'; 3) smooth non-flagged data. Let's establish some worksheet infrastructure and say that your production values are in column B and the associated time is in column A as follows:

[image: starting setup]

Part 1) In column 'C', estimate a rough data value based on a trend approximated from two points on either side of your current time step. Subtract the actual value from this approximation. The result will always be positive and quite large for a timestep with little or no production.

```
=(INTERCEPT(B1:B6,A1:A6)+(A4*SLOPE(B1:B6,A1:A6)))-B4
```

Part 2) In column 'D', add a condition for when the value computed above is larger than the actual data point. Have it use '0' to identify a point that shouldn't be included in your average. Copy this down to the end of your data as well.

```
=IF(C4>B4,0,1)
```

Our sheet now looks like this:

[image: The flagged outliers]

3) Your three element average can now be computed. In the **last** cell of column 'E', enter the following array formula. You have to accept this formula by pressing **ctrl + shift + enter**. Once that is done fill the column from ***bottom to top***:

```
=IFERROR(IF(D17=1,AVERAGE(INDEX(B12:B17,MATCH(2,1/(FIND(1,D12:D17)))),INDEX(B12:B16,MATCH(2,1/(FIND(1,D12:D16)))-COUNTIF(D17,"=0")),INDEX(B12:B15,MATCH(2,1/(FIND(1,D12:D15)))-COUNTIF(D16:D17,"=0"))),0),"")
```

This takes averages the most recent three values and allows for a skip of up to three time steps of outlier data per your problem statement. For an idea of how the completed sheet looks:

[image: smoothed time series]

This was a fun challenge, I have some ideas for a more efficient formula but this should get the job done. Please let me know how this works for you!

Cheers

***[EDIT]***

An alternative approach which allows the user to specify the number of previous entries to include is detailed below. This is a more general (preferred alternative) and picks up in place of the previously described step 3.

3Alt) In cell G2 enter a number of previous values to average, for this example I am sticking with 3. In cell E4 enter the following array expression (ctrl+shift+enter) and drag to the end of column E:

```
=IFERROR(IF(D4=1,SUM(INDEX(D:D,LARGE(($D$4:D4=1)*ROW($D$4:D4),$G$2)):D4 * INDEX(B:B,LARGE(($D$4:D4=1)*ROW($D$4:D4),$G$2)):B4)/$G$2,0),"")
```

This uses the LARGE function to find the 'nth' largest value, where *n* is the number of preceding values from the current time-step to average. Then it builds a range that extends from the found cell to the current time step. Then it multiplies the flags (0's and 1's) by each month's production value, sums them and divides by *n*. In this way months flagged as bad are set to 0 and not included in the sum.

This is a much cleaner way to achieve the desired result and has the flexibility to average different periods of time. See example of the final value below.

[image: Alternative Solution]

Comment: This works great thank you!  One thing I do wonder is why do you have 2 as for the MATCH(lookup-value,...)? and why did you do 1 divided by the find()?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it keep looking for a 1 if there are non constant flagged entires? Like, from your example for R15's average if the flagged value for R9 & R10 were 0 instead of 1, how would the code look for it to take the average of R15,R11, & R8?

Comment: How would you modify if you have more than 1 consecutive zero value?

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you. Now, to address your questions. The '1/FIND' paired with 'MATCH(2' is how I find the last flag = 1. Your problem requires that we search for the rows flagged as okay, from bottom to top (the last three). Match returns the location of the  so we achieved this by using the find and then inverting the _**largest** value less than or equal_ to the search criteria. By using a '2' it guarantees we find the last result. 

I'm not sure I follow your additional comments. The sheet currently does find non-consecutive 1's. That being said...

Comment: ...(continued) I did mention that I wanted to come up with a cleaner or more effective way to find the flagged values. I've come up with a different approach that allows for you to include any number of previously flagged data and will edit my answer to include that as an alternative.